# Simple MySql Select Queries are slow in C# but fast in MySql Workbench

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

I don't have much experience with MySql, but one of my clients have asked us to hook up to thier MySql Database. I designed the simplest query ever, a basic select statement as follows:

```
SELECT DateAndTime,
       Conveyor_Belt_Weight_Theoretical_Max_Value
FROM Conveyor_Belt
WHERE DateAndTime >= '2016-08-19 01:51:40'
  AND DateAndTime < '2016-08-19OPCSystems_To_air_AIROPCSystems_To_air_system_AIR_SYSTEM 14:45:36'
ORDER BY DateAndTime LIMIT 1000
```

In Visual Studio Code, I connect to MySql as follows:

```
DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

using (var cmd = this.MySqlConn.CreateCommand())
{
    if (this.MySqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Open) this.MySqlConn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = SQLQuery;
    using (MySqlDataReader Results = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (!Results.Read()) return null;
        _dt.Columns.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < Results.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            _dt.Columns.Add(Results.GetName(i));
        }
        _dt.Load(Results);
    }
}
return _dt;
```

I feed the exact same query into this procedure.

In mySql Workbench, it takes only 1 second.

However, in my C# application. it takes up to 6 seconds.

Comment: Then the problem is in the data transfer.  and not in the query. After all you are a fetching thousand records

Comment: I'm running the workbench on my PC as well so MySql workbench would face the same data transfer issue

Comment: Just to check, do not load in datatable and add all your data into a stringbuilder for example, to see if this is not populating datatable that is slow. Also, I don't understand why you clean columns and add then each time, the Load method takes care of creating columns by itself ...

Comment: Often the connnect is slower than most other statements..

Comment: TaW, what do you mean connect is slower?